# Image in table covers horizontal line above it

Tags: tables, spacing, graphics

I have a table with images in one of the columns. My problem is that the image overlaps the horizontal line above it, making it look bad. I first tried putting a `\\` after each `\hline`, but this causes gaps in the right most vertical line. I then tried inserting `\newline` in each cell containing an image, but I get an error that there is no line to end. Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. This would be the best way of helping you, since it shows your code and others can start working with something rather than starting from scratch. Although you're not able to upload images just yet, please do so and remove the `!` that is inserted. Someone with edit privileges will embed the images in your post.

Comment: You could try using the optional argument after the `\\ ` to specify the spacing: `\\[0.1cm]` or an extra `\\ ` after the `\hline`.

Answer (score 6):

You could add a `trim` option when including your image. Have a look at this example. The first row contains images without options, touching the lines above and below. The next row contains a correction by adding the `trim` option, using negative space of -5bp.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
Original: & \includegraphics{tex} &
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics{tex}}\\
\hline
Corrected: & \includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 -5]{tex} &
    \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[trim=0 -5 0 0]{tex}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: table with images]

The `trim` option takes four lengths as argument, specifying the amount to remove or add to each side. `trim= 1 2 3 4` would "crop" the picture by 1bp at the left, 2bp at the bottom, 3bp on the right and 4bp at the top. Here we used negative value to add some space.

The [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package provides further options for `\includegraphicx`, described in the manual.

For more complex adjustments, you could use the [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package, which provides flexible alternatives and is also well documented.

Comment: Awesome, trim was just what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the case when it is not possible to use negative trim (when you are using positive trim to crop the image), just using `\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[trim=0 0 0 5]{image}}` does the trick. So seems like it is not necessary to have a negative trim. Just the `trim` with `\raisebox` does the trick