# Pictures inside cells overlaps horizontal rules when exported to PDF

Tags: tables, diagrams, pdf, export, cell

I am new to LaTeX. 
I am trying to make a table with pictures inside the cells. Preview in ShareLatex looks fine, but when I export PDF file to my computer it looks like this. Any suggestions?

[image: Preview in Adobe Acrobat Pro]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{center}
    %\centering
    %\begin{tabular}{||M{1cm}|c|M{40mm}|c|c||}
    \begin{tabular}{||c| >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0,5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3,5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2,5cm} |
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2,5cm} ||}
        \hline
        1. & & SN74HC00N & Quad 2-input NAND gate & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC00.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC00_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        2. & & SN74HC02N & Quad 2-input NOR gate &
        \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC02.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC02_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        3. & & SN74HC04N & Hex inverter & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC04.png} &
        \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC04_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        4. & & SN74HC08N & Quad 2-input AND gate & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC08.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC08_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        5. & & SN74HC32N & Quad 2-input OR gate & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC32.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC32_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        6. & & SN74HC76N & Dual J-K flip-flop, asynchronous preset and clear & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC76.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC76_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        7. & & SN74HC86N & Quad 2-input XOR gate & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC86.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC86_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        8. & & SN74HC153N & Dual 4-line to 1-line data selector/multiplexer, non-inverting outputs & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC153.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC153_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        9. & & SN74HC190N & Synchronous presettable up/down decade counter & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC190.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC190_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        10. & & SN74HC595N & 8-bit shift registers, output latches, three-state parallel outputs & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC595.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC595_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        11. & & SN74HC4511AP & BCD to 7-segment decoder & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC4511.png} & \includegraphics[height=18mm]{74HC4511_pin.png}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \caption*{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please try to give as a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) [just the needed -minimum- code to reproduce the problem]. Images of code doesn't really help as to reproduce the problem and find a solution.

Comment: instead of code image please copy code to question. it is not fun retype a code if they already exist :-). in code we can easily show how to solve your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170941/images-in-table-going-over-cell-lines or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68590/images-inside-table-are-drawn-on-top-of-cell-borders or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41788/image-in-table-covers-horizontal-line-above-it (Every one of these has a different answer but all of them can work -I suppose- for you too)

Comment: Off-topic: Hahaha! Everyone who see the question is trying to edit (Itried too)... This is funny!

Comment: The image is just an a print screen to illustrate how the website displayed the code when I tied to copy in in to the question.

Comment: Try adding, just after  `\begin{table}`, `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}`. Also replace the `center` environment inside table with `\centering`.

Comment: @Alina Just leave a line after "Here is the code:", paste it there and then select it (all the code pasted) and press the `{}` button.

Comment: That did not solve the problem, @Bernard

Comment: Thank you for the links, @koleygr :) Unfortunately none of them worked for me

Comment: Add a bit space before the graphics by using this column definition: `>{\centering\arraybackslash\vspace{3pt}}m{2,5cm}`

Comment: @Alina: When you zoom in when viewing the PDF in your viewer, do the lines still disappear?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: Thank you so much!! It worked! :D 
I could not mark your answer as the best one since it is written as a comment :/

Comment: @Werner: yes, they did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some space before the graphics in the column description like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{table}[ht]

    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{||c| 
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0,5cm} | 
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm} | 
       >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3,5cm} |  
       >{\centering\arraybackslash\vspace{3pt}}m{2,5cm} |
       >{\centering\arraybackslash\vspace{3pt}}m{2,5cm}  |}
        \hline
        1. & & SN74HC00N & Quad 2-input NAND gate & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image} & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}\\

    \end{tabular}

    \caption*{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
% added
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand\insertimage[1]{% for shorter code
    \includegraphics[height=18mm,width=0.8\linewidth, % width is only for test,  original images are probaly narrover 
                     margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt, valign=m]{#1}%
                            }
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{my table}\label{tab:ic}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c | C|C|C|}
  \hline
        1. & & SN74HC00N & Quad 2-input NAND gate & \insertimage{74HC00.png} & \insertimage{74HC00_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        2. & & SN74HC02N & Quad 2-input NOR gate &
        \insertimage{74HC02.png} & \insertimage{74HC02_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        3. & & SN74HC04N & Hex inverter & \insertimage{74HC04.png} &
        \insertimage{74HC04_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        4. & & SN74HC08N & Quad 2-input AND gate & \insertimage{74HC08.png} & \insertimage{74HC08_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        5. & & SN74HC32N & Quad 2-input OR gate & \insertimage{74HC32.png} & \insertimage{74HC32_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        6. & & SN74HC76N & Dual J-K flip-flop, asynchronous preset and clear & \insertimage{74HC76.png} & \insertimage{74HC76_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        7. & & SN74HC86N & Quad 2-input XOR gate & \insertimage{74HC86.png} & \insertimage{74HC86_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        8. & & SN74HC153N & Dual 4-line to 1-line data selector/multiplexer, non-inverting outputs & \insertimage{74HC153.png} & \insertimage{74HC153_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        9. & & SN74HC190N & Synchronous presettable up/down decade counter & \insertimage{74HC190.png} & \insertimage{74HC190_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        10. & & SN74HC595N & 8-bit shift registers, output latches, three-state parallel outputs & \insertimage{74HC595.png} & \insertimage{74HC595_pin.png}\\
        \hline
        11. & & SN74HC4511AP & BCD to 7-segment decoder & \insertimage{74HC4511.png} & \insertimage{74HC4511_pin.png}\\
        \hline
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

- for table i suggest to use `tabularx` environment, where last tree columns are of `C` type (`C` is centering variant of `X` column).
- images are natural aligned with its bottom border. to change this to the middle of image iis used macro `valign` from package `adjustbox`
- for vertical centering of texts the definition of `X` column type is changed from `p` type to `m` type
- vertical space above and below image is determined with `margin=<left>, <bottom> <right> <top>` also from `adjustbox` package
  -for centering of table please use anly `\centering.`\begin{center} ... \end{center} only add undesired vertical space
- as can you see, table is to tall for one page (consequently page number appear in cell with "BCD to 7-segment decoder". this can be repaired with reduce images heights from 18mm to 15mm or manually split table into two parts or add `ltablex` package to preamble, which combine `tabularx` and `longtable`